# How to prevent parallel Java Web Start downloads of the same application?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

We have deployed our Java Swing application to the intranet web server, so that it can be accessed and downloaded by client machines using Java Web Start. Total size of all application files (jar files) is 130 MB.

We are now facing this problem: when user clicks on a link and initiates download procedure, a dialog with progress bar appears. While downloading, if he/she clicks on the link again, Java Web Start will initiate another download procedure. At that moment there will be two parallel downloads (two progress dialogs) of the same application. Eventually, when downloads are finished, there will be approximately 260 MB of files in user (or system) cache, proving that there were actually two (same) applications downloaded.

Is there a way to prevent multiple downloads of the same application at the same time? Is it possible to configure Java Web Start launcher so that it can detect when there is already download of the same application in progress?

Just to clarify: our client machines are not actually classic clients - they are Citrix servers serving hundreds of terminal users. So, situation where there is more than one download of the same application in the same time could easily happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered, I'll do it, so maybe one day it will be helpful to someone with the same problem. Based on the information I have and testing I did, i found that there is no way to instruct Java Web Start to detect requests for the same application (made from same user on the same machine) which is currently already downloading.

Apparently, Java Web Start will start another download process, so there will be two identical downloads of two identical application content - thus unnecessary consuming network, web server and disk resources. It's quite a problem in virtual application delivery systems like Citrix XenApp.

The one solution that comes to my mind is to create custom java launcher application that synchronizes download requests with lock file. Something like:

1. Wait in a loop (show to user some progress indicator) until lock file is created (lock is acquired).
2. Download updated app resources from server (if any): `javaws -import -silent http://someserver/jnlp-app.jnlp`
3. Start application:`javaws http://someserver/jnlp-app.jnlp`
4. Delete lock file (release lock)